# Can We Publish Windows store apps withSQlite

Tags: windows, sqlite, windows-8

Can we publish Windows 8 Store apps that includes a SQLITE server successfully to the store???

Comment: Is there any reason you think we can't? Licensing issues? Distribution size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Since the released version in spring it fully supports WinRT. See the VSIX installer packages here: http://sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: well, it won't fail just because you're using SQLite :) [Tim Heuer's blog](http://timheuer.com/blog/tags/sqlite/default.aspx) is a good reference by the way.

Comment: Yes sqlite is fully WinRT compatible now as long as you use the binary compiled for WinRT